# Creating cursor in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

a.  The procedure takes ONE input parameter for table name and TWO output parameters for “status message” and “return code”.

b.  Please pass SCORE table as your input table name.

c.  For this input table, identify the parent tables.

d.  For parent tables add a column PARENT_COLUMN of datatype INT.

Parent tables are STUDENT and GREADE_EVENT.

Any help, please.

Comment: Sorry!!! but what is your question?

Comment: I just want to add a column (PARENT_COLUMN) to two tables by using the information above.

Comment: This looks like a school assignment.